# Script that collect website in httpd.conf and get the size of the folder

Tags: linux, perl, bash, sh

enter code hereWhat I want to do it's a script that will collect the website configured in my `httpd.conf`.
Get the `DoccumentRoot` and the `ServerName`. then do a `du -s` on the document root and put the data in a file.

For now I have this command :

```
grep -E "DocumentRoot|ServerName" /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf | grep -v "#" | awk '{print $2}'
```

it give me output on separate line but I have no Idea how I can parse the output so I can do a `du -s` on the `DocumentRoot` and then get the `Size / DocumentRoot / ServerName` on the same line of a new file.

The desired output should be something like :

```
size - Folder -  Servername

3436712 /etc/www/htdocs/domain www.domain.qc.ca
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
grep -E "DocumentRoot|ServerName" /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf |
awk '!/#/{print $2}' |
xargs -n1 du -s
```

Or with a unique pipe :

```
grep -ioP '^\s*(?<!#)\s*(DocumentRoot|ServerName)\s+\K.*' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf |
xargs -n1 du -s
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, When I try the Unique pipe, I got an error :grep: unrecognized character after (?<   and the du -s got executed.

Comment: and with the grep -E, i got an /: Event not found. the problem it's related to the awk '!/#/{print $2}'  without the awk it work but with it, I got the error.    Thanks

Comment: You could change it to grep -v ^# that is the awk bit of above. Since all that is doing is removing any that match # at the start

Comment: thanks, I manage to make it work but the problem is : Since I grep for DocumentRoot & ServerName, my grep output look like this :  'DocumentRoot /etc/www/htdocs/domain
    ServerName www.domain.qc.ca
    DocumentRoot /etc/www/htdocs/site
    ServerName www.site.org
    DocumentRoot /etc/www/htdocs/bob
    ServerName www.bob.ca'                                  so with the xargs du -s, i got an error every 2 line and at the end I wish to have an output like this :      3436712 /etc/www/htdocs/domain www.domain.qc.ca

Comment: Don't know what's this mess means, but I have added `-n` switch to `xargs` in my response, it will be better